# PHP shows "{" or "[" for JSON Object Attributes sent via Angular $http

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, http-post

I've never seen this problem before, and I can't find the issue anywhere online. I'm using Angular to post form data to a PHP page. I'm using the file_get_contents() method of retrieving the POST data, which is a simple JSON object.

The problem arises with the data attributes - when I assign php vars to the data, they always have the value "{" or "[" (I echo'd and logged them). Any idea what could be causing this problem?

The relevant form declaration:

```
<form name="itemForm" ng-if="true" id="newItemForm" class="add-item" ng-submit="addItem(itemForm)">
            <input type="text" class="form-control data-entry"  ng-model="itemForm.itemType" placeholder="Type" ng-focus="true">
```

Here's my Angular function:

```
$scope.addItem = function(itemForm) {
        $http.post("../ajax/addItem.php", itemForm).success(function(data) {
            //console.data(JSON.stringify(itemForm));
            console.log(data);
            currItem = itemForm;
            itemsArr.push(angular.copy(itemForm));
            $scope.itemForm = defaultForm;
            getItem();
        });
    };
```

partial PHP:

```
<?php 

$params = file_get_contents('php://input');

if($params){
    $item = $params["item"];
    $type = $item["itemType"];
    //get other parameters, insert into MySQL database

    echo json_encode(["type = " => $type]);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using string-based keys for your array. In Javascript terms, that has to be represented as an Object, which uses `{}` as the delimiters. Proper arrays, which use `[]`, only accept numerical keys.

And note that `type =` as an array key is somewhat redundant. Why not just `type`?

Answer (score 1):

The `file_get_contents` function returns a string, so the `$params` variable is a string not an array.  However, strings in php can be accessed in an array like fashion (except the key must be a number).  In your code `$item = $params["item"]` should will give you a `php warning` and php will automatically assume an index of 0 since the key you gave was not a number.  This is why you were getting `{` or `[` when you `echoed` the data from php (because valid json is enclosed by {} or []).

To use `$params` as an array like you are trying to do you first need to do `$params = json_decode($params)`.  This will only work assuming you have a valid json string in the file you are reading from.